# How do I prevent a dropdown menu to move/affect content/elements of a web page?

Tags: html, css

I have searched both here and elsewhere on the internet for an answer, but have not found anything that has solved my problem. I also tried to include relevant code only, but I am sorry if I included something irrelevant.

I have made a navigation bar with 4 alternatives (or 4 buttons, if you prefer), where the fourth one is a dropdown menu with 3 additional alternatives that are visible while hovering over the fourth button. I have also added an image to the web page, but the problem I am having is that, while hovering the fourth alternative and thus displaying the dropdown menu, the image moves.

I would like to make it so that the picture, and any additional content for that matter, stays at the same place while the cursor is hovering over the fourth alternative.

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="logoquotebar">
</div>

<a class="navbutton1" href="#"> Navbutton 1 </a>
<a class="navbutton2" href="#"> Navbutton 2 </a>
<a class="navbutton3" href="#"> Navbutton 3 </a>
<a class="navbutton4" href="#"> Navbutton 4 </a>

<div class="dropdowncontent" href="#">


<a id="link1" href="#"> Link 1 </a>
<a id="link2" href="#"> Link 2 </a>
<a id="link3" href="#"> Link 3 </a>

</div>

<div id="logopic">
<img src="E7.jpg" width="148" height="120">
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#logoquotebar {
background-color:white;
width:1200px;
height:200px;
}

#logopic {
position:fixed;
margin-top:-160px;
}

.navbutton4 {
display:block;
width:236px;
height:35px;

background-color:#8B6969;
text-align:center;
line-height:33px;
font-family:Verdana;

-webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
transition-duration:0.4s;

margin-left:964px;
margin-top:-35px;
}

.dropdowncontent {
display:none;
width:236px;
height:105px;

background-color:white;
text-align:center;
line-height:33px;
font-family:Verdana;

margin-left:964px;

-webkit-transition-duration:0.2s;
transition-duration:0.2s;

}

#link1 {
display:block;
width:236px;
height:35px;
}

#link2 {
display:block;
width:236px;
height:35px;
}

#link3 {
display:block;
width:236px;
height:35px;
}

.navbutton4:hover + .dropdowncontent {
display:block;
}

.dropdowncontent:hover {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: try `absolute` or `fixed` positioning I guess... show some code too

Comment: We can't help you without your code!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kukkuz I have tried fixed position, and I just learned how to indent code in my question. Hehe.

Comment: @PaulRedmond Fixed it, it's in the question!

Answer (score 0):

```
 .dropdowncontent {
   position: absolute;
   z-index:100;
 }
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

```
 .dropdowncontent {
   position: fixed;
 }
```

That should work